# MongoDB: Cannot refer to field with a space

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection `PH_location`, and this is one document in it:

```
> db.PH_location.findOne({})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579662fec773d83e625f71e8"),
    "﻿Postal Code" : 2800,
    "town" : "Bangued",
    "province" : "Abra",
    "metro" : ""
}
```

I am having trouble referring to the field `"Postal Code"`. Find and Update operations that use the field simply cannot locate it. For instance:

```
> db.PH_location.findOne({},{"Postal Code":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("579662fec773d83e625f71e8") }
```

and

```
> db.PH_location.updateMany({}, {$rename:{"Postal Code":"ZIP_code"}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 2271, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: You probably have non printable characters in your field's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bet it is a non-breaking space and not a regular space.

Try this:

```
db.PH_location.find({"Postal\u00a0Code" : 2800})
```

You can debug the characters in the keys using this:

```
function codepoints(str) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        result += "'" + str[i] + "':" + str.charCodeAt(i) + ", ";
    }
    return result;
}
function walk(obj) {
  for (prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && isNaN(prop)) {
      print(prop + " " + codepoints(prop));
      walk(obj[prop]);
    }
  }
}
var cursor = db. PH_location.find()
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    obj = cursor.next();
    walk(obj);
}
```

Look for the spaces `' '` in the output. You will see:

```
' ':32
```

if it is a space, or

```
' ':160
```

if it is a non- breaking space, or some other code if it is some other char.

Comment: > you sure  db.PH_location.find({"Postal\u00a0Code" : 2800}) does work?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. Assuming that it is in fact a non-breaking space. :-)

Comment: I'm using 3.2 mongo shell.

Comment: There was a 'Zero Width Space' before the text. So db.PH_location.findOne({},{"\ufeffPostal Code":1}) did the trick :)